# How to use c:if after using c:remove on session variable?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying to remove an error message after setting it in session. The code inside the if is run even though im removing the attribute.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <c:if test="${not empty success}">
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                ${success}
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <c:remove var="success"/>
        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                ${error}
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <c:remove var="error"/>
        <form action="Login">
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>Username: </p><input class="form-control" type="text" name="uname" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>Password: </p><input class="form-control" type="password" name="pword" required>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            <a href="register.jsp" class="btn btn-primary">Register</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The error messages are being displayed when they are set, but the div is still showing after removing it.
I've also tried setting the scope to session.

```
<c:remove var="success" scope="session"/>
```

I've attached an image of the login page showing the empty boxes when starting project.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to be good to me. Do you have the core taglib declared in your JSP file? The following line should be in your JSP file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Comment: I have done this in my header.jsp which i include in the first line of my login.jsp and register.jsp...
The really odd thing is that it works like a charm in the register.jsp which has the exact same include and exact same code.
Thank you for your comment though

Comment: You were right, to include the tag in my header wasn't enough to do the job, i had to include it on my login.jsp!